# How to play Apple Music and Radio (Beats 1) on iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, apple-music

I've updated to Yosemite 10.10.4 but I can't find a way to listen Beats 1 on my Mac...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple Music require iTunes 12.2, which is not included in Yosemite 10.10.4 so, soon, Apple should release another update exclusively for iTunes where there should be a button to play Apple Music.

You can get that update from the iTunes menu - select **Check for Updates...**

If that update isn't rolled out or available, you can listen here:

http://itsliveradio.apple.com/streams/hub01/session01/256k/prog.m3u8

Comment: iTunes is being delayed from the time they should have released it (10:00 Central). If you call apple support they will just say it should be out later today, so just check for the update periodically.

Comment: Update: iTunes 12.2 out.

Answer (score 6):

You need iTunes 12.2 - presumably will be out any minute now…

Update 07:30 GMT 1st July.
OS X 10.10.4 iTunes 12.2 & iOS 8.4 all now available & successfully installed here.

Comment: As of Tue Jun 30 23:04:15 UTC 2015 all the caching issues and load issues seem to be resolved. Is anyone still not seeing the update when running software update or checking in iTunes for updates?

Comment: I'm still not seeing the update in the Mac App Store.

When I check for updates in iTunes, I get a dialog that says "The iPhone software update server could not be contacted. An unknown error occurred (-50).

Comment: I was finally able to download the installer from https://www.apple.com/itunes/.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the Radio tab, click on the plus sign next to 'My Stations' and search for 'Beats 1' it'll be added to your stations and you can stream it. This works with iTunes 12.1.

I'm guessing this only works if you've updated to the latest Music app on iOS, but I haven't tested without upgrading my iPhone.

Comment: This is about OS X, not iOS...

Comment: I confirmed it works on OS X. http://www.theverge.com/2015/6/30/8872605/beats-1-itunes-now-available